# styling a component in react

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a function that returns a special style :

```
const handleBorderColor =()=>{
        if(border){
            return {'background-color': '#f3f3f3' , 'border' : 'solid 1px #00bfa5'}
        }

    }
```

and when I call it like this in a component it works:

```
<div className="form-input" style={handleBorderColor()} />
```

but for one of my components I have extra styles (I have height: 100 ) and this is wrong:

```
<div className="form-input" style={{handleBorderColor(),height: '100px'}}/>
```

how can I give styles to my component correctly?

Comment: you are getting the problem because in your code the styles finally becomes: style: {{ {'background-color': '#f3f3f3' , 'border' : 'solid 1px #00bfa5'}, height: '100px'}}. I mean there is an object in you style..

Comment: thanks I got what you mean!

Comment: hi. why don't you create a CSS file and import it in your react file. it will make it much easier.

Comment: @R.Kazmi I think it is a good solution but how can I call my handleBorderColor in your way?

Comment: you don't have to call when page renders it will automatically pick up style from CSS file. you just mention css class in your component html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem in this way:
my function :

```
const handleBorderColor =(style)=>{
        if(border){
            return {...style , 'background-color': '#f3f3f3' , 'border' : 'solid 1px #00bfa5'}
        }else{
            return {...style}
        }

    }
```

and my component:

```
<div className="form-input" style={handleBorderColor({height: '100px'})}/>
```